# Menu not working properly with left click

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, menu

I am working on a single scrolling page site and the navigation. The menu works fine for navigating to different areas of the current page. however there are 2 links to pages on on the same site and another on a different site that only work to with a right click and open in new tab/window. it behalves the same in all the major browsers.

the html is fine as if i copy it from source and try in a blank html file it works. The theme i am using is one engine and i am using page layout to define the sections.

```
<li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-38">
    <a href="http://www.extwebsite.com" class="active">Link to external website</a>
</li>
```

It is also not working to tab to the link and press enter.

Comment: There is probably some js that prevent default action on links for the anchor menu. Look for something like `e.preventDefault()` in your js files.

Comment: @vard ok thanks thats going to take a while to check ill get back to you

Comment: @vard i did a find in directory and there are 212 in my wordpress site dir. how do i find the culpret

Comment: There is 212 occurence of `e.preventDefault` in your theme folder?! That's a lot - if you search on the whole WP folder you should restrict to the theme folder only. If not, try to look on the file name, if there is any js named like menu.js or something like that. It probably should be in the main js theme file.

Comment: @vard i restricted the search to the theme folder and found 2 occurrences in the theme folder in a file maned `jquery.slicknav.min.js` i commented these out but no joy ill look into the 17 other in the theme folder